# Normal group that contains its centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying for my Algebra qual and I came across this question:

Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $N$ such that $C_G (N) \leq N$. Show that
$$
|G|\leq |N|!.
$$

Here $C_G (N)$ is the centralizer of $N$ in $G$.

So far I have tried letting $G$ act on the elements of $N$ by conjugation. This induces a homomorphism from $G$ into $S_{|N|}$ with $C_G (N)$ as the kernel. So what I can get is that

$$
\frac{|G|}{|C_G(N)|} \leq |N|!.
$$

It is here that I get stuck.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. What you overlooked is that the identity is fixed by all the conjugations, so you can view the action on $N$ by conjugation as a homomorphism to the symmetric group on $\lvert N\rvert - 1$ elements, hence

$$\frac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert C_G(N)\rvert} \leqslant (\lvert N\rvert - 1)!.$$

Comment: Thanks! Definitely overlooked that small detail.